# Where has the "Normal" Texture paint project option gone in 2.8?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am attempting to project an image onto a model, but faces with a shallow normal to the camera are not receiving protection. The "normal" option used to adjust this in 2.7, how do I do it in 2.8?

[image]

2.79 on the left 2.8 on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in a different place, but still available under the Falloff menu options.
[image]